# How to use SASS parent selector with sass module in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, react-css-modules

Consider the following

**styles.module.sass**

```
 .button
     cursor: pointer
     background: transparent
     &.active
       border-left-color: green
       border-left-width: 2px
```

Button.js

```
const MyButton = () => {
    return <button className={styles.button}>select this</button>;
};
```

How can attach the `.active` class inside of the `className` given that this is a scss module? The following wont work, as the 'active' is not in the context of the class name re-writing.

```
const MyButton = () => {
    return <button className={styles.button + "active"}>select this</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pick the `active` class from styles too like `styles.active` and have a space between classes when joining. For that, you can do any of the following:

1. You can use change to `className={styles.button + " " + styles.active}` or use template string:

```
const MyButton = () => {
    return <button className={`${styles.button} ${styles.active}`}>select this</button>;
};
```

2. You can use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
import classNames from 'classnames'
const MyButton = () => {
    return <button className={classNames(styles.button styles.active)}>select this</button>;
};
```

3. You can use [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles) component:

```
const MyButton = () => {
    return (
        <PatchStyles classNames={styles}>
            <button className="button active">select this</button>
        </PatchStyles>
    );
};
```

I personally prefer [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles) or sometimes [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) combined with [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles). As [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles) brings a big abstraction to your code, you don't need to care about applying styles to every place and missing it when applying the active class. It also allows moving to or from CSS/SCSS modules by changing just a few code lines.

About the benefits of using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames), read their documentation. It's handy when you have classes which depend on certain conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Composition

```
.button
     cursor: pointer
     background: transparent

.activeButton
     composes: button
     border-left-color: green
     border-left-width: 2px
```

then use `.activeButton` in jsx

```
const MyButton = () => {
    return <button className={styles.activeButton}>select this</button>;
};
```

Comment: I know about this, but this doesn't answer the question